# WebM / MP4 video in Android Chrome version 29.0.1547

Tags: android, html, video

WEBM / MP4 LOCAL files (from SD CARD) are not playing for me in the Android Chrome Browser (29.0.1457.59).
When i browse to this page in Android Chrome both the WEBM and MP4 are playing fine.
http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html

But if i download the 2 videos (big_buck_bunny.mp4, big_buck_bunny.webm) in the above URL in my Android Device and access them from the Chrome browser, both the videos are NOT playing for me.

I have also created an HTML page with the following VIDEO Tags. These are not working as well and i just get the BLACK Player with the controls.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fnOnLoad() {
            var video1 = document.getElementById('vid_1');
            video1.addEventListener('click', function () {
                video1.play();
            }, false);

            var video2 = document.getElementById('vid_2');
            video2.addEventListener('click', function () {
                video2.play();
            }, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" onload="fnOnLoad();">
    <video id="vid_1" controls>
        <source src="file:///mnt/sdcard/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <p>Your browser does not support H.264/MP4.</p>
    </video>
    <br />
    <br />
    <video id="vid_2" controls>
        <source src="file:///mnt/sdcard/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
        <p>Your browser does not support WebM.</p>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed in the latest beta v30.0.1599.50

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta&hl=en